# SoundPool Reverb::StartElementHandler, wrong element or attributes: boolean

Tags: android

This isn't really breaking anything, but the error is rather annoying. I'd like to eliminate it, if at all possible.

`Logcat gives me (level "E"): Reverb::StartElementHandler, wrong element or attributes: boolean`

Also notable, it gives me a message as `(level "I") prior : getpid() 14930, IPCThreadState::self()->getCallingPid() 14930`

I debugged it, where I discovered it results from my soundPool.play(). As I said, it still completely works. I'm just not too fond of errors in my logcat.

The problem child:

```
soundPool.play(resourceList.get(resourceListIndex).soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

soundPool is a SoundPool object

Google lead me to 2 websites (in Korean), but it didn't help explain the problem.

Does anyone know how to stop it from freaking out on this?